# Restrict caching images asp.net

Tags: .net

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate >
        <asp:Image  runat="server" id="img" style="max-width:100%"></asp:Image>
```

I have this image in updatePanel control. And i change it's source in the code behind like this

```
img.ImageUrl = "~/BackFile.ashx?ID=";
```

and backfile.ashx code is something like this:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(getsrc());
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(memStream,
          System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        memStream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

On my computer and oogle chrome everything worked well
But then i tested it from another laptop  on ie and opera 
and pictures stopped changing their sources.
I think it 's because caching .so how can Ш restrict it?
I just need pictures to refresh=)

UPD: it seems not be working in ie and opera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the headers to set no-cache.

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
context.Response.Expires = 0;
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

and you should use below to ignore cached data by browser:

```
img.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/BackFile.ashx?ID={0}&R={1}", <your ID>, randomNumber);
```

Comment: ooh wait a second evrything is working but i insert randomnumber instead of <My ID>  . Is it  okay? and why do i need an id and where can i get it?)

Comment: yeah good work!

I don't know where can you get your id, but you just wrote     img.ImageUrl = "~/BackFile.ashx?ID=";

Comment: oooh  sorry I got it...))))))this is an old version and i just got rid of this id it generates dynamically in ashx so i 've forgotten about it)))))thanks )))